# How can I get the branch name that is merged into target branch that trigger the pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops

Branch "1850" was merged into the branch "dev". And pipeline trigger when there is merge to branch "dev". When release is success or fail, there is a stage will send email to let user know the status of realease. And from email i cant tell which one it is. So how can i get the branch name of "1850" variable.

Update to Leo Liu-MSFT's answer:

Thanks for helping. so i make change and these error occurs. please explain why so.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i get the branch name that is merged into target branch that trigger the pipeline?

You could use the [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables) `System.PullRequest.SourceBranch`, which return the branch that is being reviewed in a pull request.

[image]

As test, I add a inline powershell task to output this variable:

```
Write-Host "The merged target branch is:-" $(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)
```

Then we could get the value is `refs/heads/1805`.

We could use a command line task to parse that path to get the branch name:

```
set BranchName=$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)
for %%a in (%BranchName%) do echo %%~nxa
```

[image]

**Update:**

As I test, it works fine on my side with following code:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SourceBranchName;]$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)"
```

Remove the `isOutput=true`.

Then, I could get the variable `SourceBranchName` by the command line task:

```
echo  $(SourceBranchName)
```

[image]

According to your error, it seems the error comes from your powershell task itself or the agent. So, please try to use **hosted agent** with **Inline powershell** task to check if you still have this issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i updated my question. Hope u could crack the case for me. Still new to azure devops, quite headache

Comment: @PhucVuong, Check my updated answer for some more info.

Comment: I thought isOutput=true necessary. as i need to use it in SendGrid Email task.